# I added library to maven on bintray but can't download it from gradle ? (Android)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, bintray, jcenter

I have this lib [CustomTimePicker](https://bintray.com/abdelsattar/CustomTimePicker/CustomTimePicker) and added it to bintray and link it to JCenter and try to add it my project like that

```
compile 'com.omarali:customTimePicker:1.0.0'
```

and while trying to sync gradle it gives me this error

how can I solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: It should work. When you try to download the files from the UI, does it work?

Comment: I really don't understand your question

Comment: does download the file from JCenter UI in the web browser works for you?

Answer (score 0):

I tried downloading the dependency using pom.xml file and it worked.
I can also see the package in [Jcenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/CustomTimePicker).

You can click `I'm the creator` button and it can be linked to your [package](https://bintray.com/abdelsattar/CustomTimePicker/customTimePicker).